# Live input validation of 4-digit prefixes with optional 8 digits at the end

Tags: regex, validation

it's my following regex:

```
/^08(17|18|19|31|32|33|38|59|77|78)[0-9]{0,8}$/
```

if i put 08 in input field will showing notice error, what I want is if i input 0817 will showing success, if i input 08 i want don't appear notice error. maybe the solution is to use don't capturing group in regex. but how to do that?

it's my prefix validation what i want:

```
0817, 0818, 0819, 0831, 0832, 0833, 0838, 0859, 0877, 0878
```

Comment: Can you show us the full range of what you are trying to match?  Your current regex won't match `0817` either.

Comment: I think `08` should be part of the alternation: `/^(08|17|18|19|31|32|33|38|59|77|78)[0-9]{0,8}$/`? Best is to use `/^(08|1[7-9]|3[1238]|59|7[78])[0-9]{0,8}$/`.

Comment: You should update this question with pertinent progress and details rather than posting [duplicate questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38740717/prefix-validation-with-regular-expression). Now, I see, you need to allow `08` and then only the 2-digit chunks from the group. Try [`^08(?:(?:17|18|19|31|32|33|38|59|77|78)[0-9]{0,8})?$`](https://regex101.com/r/xC7mT4/3). Or a more efficient [`^08(?:(?:1[789]|3[1-38]|59|7[78])[0-9]{0,8})?$`](https://regex101.com/r/xC7mT4/4). If any of this works the way you expect, please leave a comment so that I could post an answer with explanations.

Comment: _if i input 0817 will showing success, if i input 08 i want don't appear notice error_ if there are more than 2 kind of output (succes, error, no notice...) the problem is not in the regex, but in the code. Regex matching is boolean.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew i don't know what is wrong but in my program after entering the number 0, and then I enter the number 8, even out notice error

Comment: What are you using? Environment, library, method? *How* are you using the regex?

Comment: you can try https://regex101.com/r/xC7mT4/5 , if i input 0 or 081 it's error

Comment: Ok, try [`^08?(?:(?:1[789]?|3[1238]?|59?|7[78]?)[0-9]{0,8})?$`](https://regex101.com/r/xC7mT4/7). Can't you explain the specifications in the question? **I updated the comment**.

Comment: But there still can be 0 to 8 digits after those prefixes, right? Try the [`^0(?:8(?:(?:1(?:[789][0-9]{0,8})?|3(?:[1238][0-9]{0,8})?|5(?:9[0-9]{0,8})?|7(?:[78][0-9]{0,8})?)?)?)?$`](https://regex101.com/r/xC7mT4/8)

Comment: yeah, that's right thank you bro it's work @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: I added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to implement a *live input validation* for your codes that consist of 4-digit set prefixes and then 0 to 8 arbitrary digits.

The point is that you cannot make the subpatterns optional *sequentially*, you need to use *nested* optional groups to require a left hand digit to be present before the right-hand one.

The pattern becomes rather untidy, but that is the only way to make it work:

```
^0(?:8(?:1(?:[789][0-9]{0,8})?|3(?:[1238][0-9]{0,8})?|5(?:9[0-9]{0,8})?|7(?:[78][0-9]{0,8})?)?)?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xC7mT4/9)

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `0` - an obligatory `0`
- `(?:`

  - `8` - obligatory `8`

    - `(?:`
    - `1`  - obligatory `1` followed by...
    - `(?:` - an optional group matching either...

      - `[789]` - `7`, or `8`, or `9` followed with
      - `[0-9]{0,8}` - 0 to 8 *any* digits
    - `)?` - (end of the optional group after `1`)
    - `|` - or
    - `3(?:[1238][0-9]{0,8})?` - (similar to above)
    - `|` - or
    - `5(?:9[0-9]{0,8})?` - (similar to above)
    - `|`  - or
    - `7(?:[78][0-9]{0,8})?` - (similar to above)
  - `)?` - end of the *optional* group matching the `8` and all after it
- `)?` - the whole part after the first `0` is *optional*.
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: It looks like I had an extra, redundant group, removed and added explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a non-capturing group. You only need `?` for an optional occurrence. It will consider valid for 0 or 1 occurrence.

```
/^08(17|18|19|31|32|33|38|59|77|78)?[0-9]{0,8}$/
```

Prove: https://regex101.com/r/xC7mT4/1

Comment: I've updated the answer with a validation prove. Maybe you should copy the error here for us to see